# How to configure middleware to skip dynamic route

Tags: go, go-echo

I'm using echo-labstack and I'm implementing a JWT validation. I'd like the validating route to be unprotected by the JWT middleware but the route is a route like '/validate/:token'.

Is there a way to match this particular route without having to unprotect all routes that start with '/validate/'?

Comment: For now as a quick fix i ended up doing 2 groups with echo.Group(), one for protected routes and one for unprotected. Doesn't feel very clean though

Comment: Two groups would be the normal approach. Why doesn't it seem clean?